# Ordered forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an Array of elements and I need to loop over them getting a value from a server at each pass. With the following code I am getting 
all the results mixed, due to the asynchronous call in the forEach loop. I need the results to be shown in the same order as in the Array.

```
var en_devices= [
  ["72", "Device 1"],
  ["73", "Device 2"],
  ["74", "Device 3"],
  ["75", "Device 4"],
  ["76", "Device 5"],
  ["5158", "Device 6"]
];

en_devices.forEach(element => {
    $.get('/check-energy/'+element[0], function(data){
      content = "<div class='service'>"+element[1]+"</div> <div class='watt'>"+data+"</div><br/>";
      $('#description-en').append(content);
  });
 });
```

Comment: Could you write your expexted result ???

Comment: Then create the necessary target elements upfront, give them something you can identify them by (like set the device id in a custom data attribute maybe), and then inside the AJAX callback put the received data into the corresponding one …?

Comment: You can use an async function. (Google async/await.) Then you'd write `for (const element of en_devices) { const data = await $.get(...); content = ...; }`

Comment: You should save all the results to an array in their correct positions. After getting all the results, append the data from the array one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$.get` is [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) then it returns a promise and you can use asynchronous programming.

As @CherryDT said, utilize it in an `async` function. If you don't have one, use it an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) - Immediately Invoked Function Expression:

```js
(async () => {
  for (let element of en_devices) {
    const data = await $.get('/check-energy/' + element[0]);
    const content = "<div class='service'>" + element[1] + "</div> <div class='watt'>" + data + "</div><br/>";
    $('#description-en').append(content);
  }
})();
```

### UPDATE:

As @huyts pointed, the above method calls the API one at time. To make it parallel, use `Promise.all`:

```js
(async () => {
  const promises = en_devices.map(element =>
    $.get('/check-energy/' + element[0])
    .then(data => [element[1], data])
  );

  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  for (let result of results) {
    const content = "<div class='service'>" + result[0] + "</div> <div class='watt'>" + result[1] + "</div><br/>";
    $('#description-en').append(content);
  }
})();
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you can only execute one request at a time, and have to wait until that request finishes, which is not very efficient.

Comment: That is true :)

Answer (score 0):

See [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```
const en_devices= [
  ["72", "Device 1"],
  ["73", "Device 2"],
  ["74", "Device 3"],
  ["75", "Device 4"],
  ["76", "Device 5"],
  ["5158", "Device 6"]
];

const length = en_devices.length;
const promises = [];
const results = Array(length).fill(null);

en_devices.forEach((element, index) => {
    promises.push(
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $.get('/check-energy/'+element[0], function(data){
                content = "<div class='service'>"+element[1]+"</div> <div class='watt'>"+data+"</div><br/>";
                results[index] = content;
                resolve();
            }
        })
    );
});

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    for (const result of results) $('#description-en').append(result);
});
```